# ios 5 UIPageViewController changing transition style to scroll

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, uipageviewcontroller

I am creating ebook application but it has to support from ios5 onwards. I want to do it quickly and efficiently too. I am planning to use UIPageviewController, but for ios5 it supports only curl animation, and i need to support scroll animation as well for page movements, which we get on ios6.
So, can i do this with ios5 using pageview controller, the contents which I am showing are images. 
Ideally i like to use page view controller, as many of things it handle itself, such as page flipping, page movement when tapping on page end area, and its curl animation is better than other available options.
Please help, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still has this problem, check out [R4PageViewController](https://github.com/srdanrasic/R4PageViewController). It supports iOS 5, 6 and 7 and has iOS 7 like scrolling effect (which can be disabled).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution use the following snippet to detect the current iOS version and use the transition styles correspondingly:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")){
  //UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
}else{
  //UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found [RAPageViewController](https://github.com/evadne/RAPageViewController). I reimplemented Apple's PhotoScroller sample with it with only minimal changes. My repo is [RAPageScroller](https://github.com/proxi/RAPhotoScroller).

Comment: For what I can see, RAPageViewController use UICollectionViewController that is iOS6+...

Comment: It is true of the entire project, but if you use just RAPageViewController.m directly, it is iOS5 compatible. At least it was at the time of my answer.